# Create External Table in Impala on a Parquet directory with multiple parquet files with different schemas

Tags: hadoop, impala

In Spark, we can read multiple parquet files with different schemas by setting  mergedSchema option to true. Is there any similar functionality in Impala that allows us to point the External table to a directory that has multiple parquet files with different schema?

Example: 
We have MEDICAL.parquet directory, under it we have two sub-directories: data_supplier_id=140060 and data_supplier_id=140059, under each of these sub-directories, we have other sub-directories for each files like file_uuid=vwefvkn-dfw16563e-qebebebeb, then under each of these file_uuid=... directories, we have actual parquet files, which each file_uuid=... can potentially have different schema.

In Spark, we just point the spark to the top level directory (in this case Medical.parquet) and it reads all the data under it in a single Dataset.

Is there a way in Impala to point it to MEDICAL.parquet file when creating External table and load all the data to it? instead of creating External table on each file_uuid=... directory.

Comment: Looks like your directory structure was intended for a single _partitioned table_. And different partitions may have different schemas as long as it follows a "backwards compatible" pattern i.e. you start from the "oldest" design and add columns as the design evolves (columns that disappear in files will be shown as Nulls). But that table structure must be **designed** and **maintained**, like in a regular DB in a regular IT dept with non-regression tests etc. _(although that could be scripted, e.g. in a Spark job)_

Comment: For more context see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072390/spark-hive-key-differences-between-hive-and-parquet-from-the-perspective-of-tabl

Comment: For your last point, no, in the Hadoop perspective it makes no sense to point a table (or a job) to a file. Because it's a distributed processing platform, jobs run on multiple machines and produce multiple files, that are stacked to a single HDFS dir on completion. A single file means nothing.